# как правильно загрузить Maven проект в eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

как правильно загрузить Maven проект в eclipse?
есть у меня папка проекта, в нем два файла pom.xml и src - в которой много пакетов с классами.
   1 Сделал импорт проекта в eclipse.
 [image: после импорта]

2 Maven build
[image: Maven build]

Теперь такая структура проекта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь когда я хочу запустить стартовый класс получаю сообщение
**Error: Could not find or load main class ua.kiev.makson.gui.StartProgram**
   pom.xml мой

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>makson.kiev</groupId>
<artifactId>TFile</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.17</version>
     </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
       <artifactId>fest-swing</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.turn</groupId>
       <artifactId>ttorrent</artifactId>
       <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>       
   </dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
</build>
```

Развернутая структура проекта

[image: Развернутая структура проекта]

Comment: Покажи свой `pom.xml` и как запускаешь проект?

Comment: @Темка тожe  добавил pom.xml. , что значит как запускаю проект? Run/ StartProgram

Comment: `pom.xml` стоит добавлять не как картинку, а сам текст. Плюс сделай скриншот развёрнутой структуры проекта. У меня есть подозрение, что твой `src/main/java` пустой

Comment: @Темка тоже внес изменения, развернутая структура проекта и pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе надо перенести свою папку `ua` (корневой пакет твоего проекта) из каталога `src` в `src/main/java`. Возможно появятся другие проблемы, т.к. из скриншота неясно, что находится в каталогах `tests` и `UnknownError`, но исходная ошибка должна пропасть

Answer (score 1):

Для начала у вас должна быть правильная стуктура проекта - [смотрите здесь](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)
Классы приложения долджны лежать в src/main/java, тесты - src/test/java. У вас, судя по картинке лежат просто в src/main.

Сделайте все правильно, потом нажмите ALT-F5, чтобы Eclipse подхватил изменения.

Для компиляции и запуска Maven проекта в Eclipse добавьте в pom.xml конфигурацию maven-exec-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version><!-- посмотрите последнюю версию в maven central --></version>
</plugin>
```

Для запуска:

- зайдите в меню Run Configurations и создайте новый Maven Build
- в поле Base Directory выберите ваш проект
- в поле Goals пишите "compile exec:java"
- нажмите кнопку Add: в поле Parameter Name пишите **exec.mainClass**, в поле Value ваш Main-класс - **ua.kiev.makson.gui.StartProgram**